# Mysql- how to select last 100 records from a table

Tags: php, mysql

This is php/mysql code

```
$view->pch = $db->Query("SELECT from_unixtime(`pauc_date`), `pauc_ad_id`, `pauc_domain`, `pauc_word`, `pauc_referer`, `pauc_ip`, `pauc_country`
                         FROM publisher_ad_units_clicks 
                         WHERE pauc_user_id=?", "i", $USER_ID);
```

I need to change this query to get only last 100 rows. because table has thousands of rows and slow down the page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL [`ORDER BY..LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html):

```
SELECT from_unixtime(pauc_date), pauc_ad_id, pauc_domain, pauc_word, pauc_referer, pauc_ip, pauc_country
FROM publisher_ad_units_clicks
where pauc_user_id=?
ORDER BY pauc_date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working' , is it throwing an error? not the correct results?

Comment: i think problem with,   where pauc_user_id=?     page not loading HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: problem with using ORDER BY pauc_date DESC
LIMIT 100 after pauc_user_id=?","i",$USER_ID

Comment: thisis my full code with your answer                                                 $view->pch = $db->Query("SELECT from_unixtime(pauc_date), pauc_ad_id, pauc_domain, pauc_word, pauc_referer, pauc_ip, pauc_country
FROM publisher_ad_units_clicks
where pauc_user_id=?","i",$USER_ID
ORDER BY pauc_date DESC
LIMIT 100
);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use limit in your mysql query. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)

```
$view->pch = $db->Query("SELECT from_unixtime(`pauc_date`), `pauc_ad_id`, `pauc_domain`, `pauc_word`, `pauc_referer`, `pauc_ip`, `pauc_country`
                         FROM publisher_ad_units_clicks 
                         WHERE pauc_user_id=? LIMIT 0, 100", "i", $USER_ID);
```